# Phonegap and Firebase integration with JS framework

Tags: cordova, firebase, angularfire, phonegap-desktop-app

I am an android developer. For a cross-platform app I want to use Phonegap and for the DB I want to use Firebase. Now there are so many things in the internet regarding JS framework. There is Angularfire, Angularfire 2, Ember etc. I am really confused what to learn and where to start. 
Can anyone guide me for which thing to put together to be able to make a cross-platform app using Phonegap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So my first question will be ask

1. So my first question will be ask yourself which framework are you comfortable with Angular,react,etc.
2. If your inclined towards angular you should try out ionic (depending on your angular framework preference. i.e Ionic 1 or Ionic 2) and for react react-native or aurelia.

   3. As for firebase you can check out their youtube link for a very detailed explanation as to how to use their sdk and make sure you learn the basics of nosql and how to set rules and stuff. ([link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP4bf6IHJJQehibu6ai__cg))

Now for your learning purposes try what you did with android. **Build and test**. If your stuck somewhere google it.
You can try [nraboy](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com) and many other.
JS can be tricky at time's always check your console for errors.
Good Luck